# Given a group describe its topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I just started a course in algebraic topology and we recently discussed how every group is the fundamental group of some topology.  What we haven't talked about is determining the topology from the group.  So, given a fundamental group, what buzz words should I google if I want to learn how to determine the associated topology.

Edit:  Eliminated my example of $SO(3)/A_5$ from  the question.

Comment: The general answer to this type of question is called a [Eilenberg-MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space).

Comment: You'll need to explain how $A_5$ is a normal subgroup of $SO(3)$, before we can know what the quotient group $SO(3)/A_5$ is.

Comment: Let $g,h\in A_5$ where $A_5$ is the group of symmetries of an icosahedran.  So, intuitively, in the group of rotations of 3 space (i.e. SO(3)) a symmetric rotation is normal.  I.e. $gh=hg$.

Comment: The quotient you've written down is not a group because $A_5$ is not a normal subgroup. It is a 3-manifold called Poincare dodecahedral space. Its fundamental group is the binary icosahedral group, which is a double cover of $A_5$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Could you indicate a reference book about fundamental (geometrical) groups giving examples like the one you just gave ?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, it's not clear to me that I've answered the OP's question. It sounds like the OP wants a space whose fundamental group is related to the group $SO(3)$. There is a space whose fundamental group is $SO(3)$, but it can only be described pretty indirectly: it's the classifying space $BSO(3)_d$, where the subscript emphasizes that we're equipping $SO(3)$ with the discrete topology rather than the usual topology.

Comment: Ah OK.  I was careless in assuming $A_5$ was normal.  So, I'll edit my question appropriately.

Comment: The phrasing "determine the topology" suggests you want to find a *unique* space with given fundamental group. You just want to find one, I guess? There are infinitely many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a (discrete) group $G$, there are many spaces with fundamental group $G$. There is a distinguished choice up to homotopy, namely the [Eilenberg-MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) $K(G, 1)$, or equivalently the [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) $BG$. Among all spaces with fundamental group $G$ it's distinguished by the fact that its [higher homotopy groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) are all trivial.